# Include full mgcv::gam() summary() with stargazer()

Tags: r, stargazer, gam, mgcv

I am trying to create a table of my `mgcv::gam()` summary with the stargazer package. See code below.

```
library(stargazer)
library(mgcv)

set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
b <- gam(y~(x0)+(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
summary(b)

stargazer(b, type = "text", summary = T, colnames=T, rownames = T, df=T, digits=3)
```

The output does not include the information for the fitted smooth splines (or even for each knot). Do you know how to include all of the information included in the summary in this `stargazer` table?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the information for the fitted smooth splines (or even for each knot)"?

Comment: This looks like a bug (*stargazer* claims to support *mgcv* models estimated via `gam()`). It shouldn't be reporting (be default) coefficient estimates for basis functions (those aren't knots). I suggest you speak with the maintainer.